# Expanded search box - previous searches

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I like the new 'expanded search box'. At this moment, it expands when you start typing. Very good. If memory serves me well, the original box (maybe a Firefox feature) showed previous searches in a drop-down box.

I'm not sure that's a good feature, so I'm asking here. Would you like the search box to show previous questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think waffles' suggestion is good, but *until it's implemented*, it would be nice if the previous searches are again shown in a drop-down box. At the moment, *nothing* is offered, which I find mildly annoying.

Comment: fixing the rendering bug in a browser general way is going to be a bit of a nightmare

Comment: Do you mean [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102056/auto-expanding-search-box-doesnt-line-up-with-auto-complete-suggestions-in-chrom) posted by Cody? I'd rather have this buggy version than _nothing!_

Comment: I'd rather have the old search box, you know, the one that didn't make me disoriented and nauseated every time I tried to use it... At least make the damn thing an option to turn off. I know Jeff and Joel are generally against a proliferation of options, and instead preferring smart defaults. I completely agree. But in this case, the smart default is *way too smart* and very annoying to some people. Even Google, who is famous for not having many options, gave us the option to turn it off. As I told Jeff in a comment, if I *couldn't* turn off InstantSearch or whatever, I'd switch to Bing.

Comment: @Cody, this could be a dupe of your question.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would like it to work like Amazon and Google do.

I would like it to suggest searches based on the first few letters I type in, it would save me from typos and help quite a bit.